# Is it possible to add apklibs to dependencies with Intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, apklib

I would like to add apklibs file to the dependencies of my project. Is it possible?

I'm using IntelliJ without Maven.

Thank you

Comment: If you are using Maven, it should work automatically, otherwise import it as a new library module and add this module to the dependencies of your app.

Comment: what do you suggest is creating a new library module and extracting the content of all the apklibs in it and then add this to my project dependencies? Am I right?

Comment: You can import the module from the existing sources that are already extracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract apklib into some directory and import a new module from the existing sources, this module should be Android library module that you can add to the dependencies of your app.

Comment: Is there any document to guide me for extract apklib? thanks.